# Django: Would object creation involving FK still work when the 2 tables involved are in different databases?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a Django model:

```
class Note(models.Model) : 
    text = models.TextField() 
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

If `Note` and `User` are located on different databases, would the 
following still work?

```
note = Note(text='hello world', owner=request.user)
```

I understand that join will not work across databases, but will 
creating object instances using FK like above still work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not support cross-database relations, as stated in their documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations

So no, your snippet won't work.